# Animating two divs to loop right to left indefinitely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Here's my code:

### HTML

```
<div class="screen screen1"></div>
<div class="screen screen2"></div>
```

### CSS

```
.screen{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#001;
    background-image: radial-gradient(white 15%, transparent 16%),
    radial-gradient(white 15%, transparent 16%);
    background-size:60px 60px;
    background-position: 0 0, 30px 30px;
}

.screen2{
    left: 100%;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    screen1 = $('.screen1');
    screen2 = $('.screen2');

    move(screen1, screen2);
});

function move(first, second){
    first.animate({left: '-100%'}, 3000, function(){
        first.css('left', '100%');
        move(second, first);
    });
    second.animate({left: 0}, 3000);
}
```

I want to animate two divs to make an infinite background repeating animation using jQuery. I came this far, and it works good for the most part except for the small pause that happens when I send `.screen1` to the right.

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mavisme/a1275tuv/

How do I fix it to run smoothly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are unsatisfied with the "speeding up" and "slowing down" at the beginning and end of each cycle. Have a look at 'easing':

```
function move(first, second) {
    first.animate({
        left: '-100%',
    }, 3000, 'linear', function() {
        first.css('left', '100%');
        move(second, first);
    });
    second.animate({
        left: 0
    }, 3000, 'linear');
}
```

> easing (default: swing)
>
> A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 3):

You should totally drop that and try <s>jQuery</s> CSS animations:

```css
@keyframes animate {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -60px 0;
  }
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.screen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #001;
  background-image: radial-gradient(white 15%, transparent 16%), radial-gradient(white 15%, transparent 16%);
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  animation: animate 300ms linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="screen"></div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly but the reason I'm using jQuery is that I'm making a game which needs to detect collisions with objects in the background. Which means that the background can't be a gradient and will have to be some more divs shaped by CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Animating two divs to loop right to left indefinitely

Here's my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/a1275tuv/5/

```
 $(function(){
        var x = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            x-=1;
            $('.screen').css('background-position', x + 'px 0');
        }, 10);
    })
```